# How are null values in C# string interpolation handled?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In C# 6.0, string interpolations are added.

```
string myString = $"Value is {someValue}";
```

How are null values handled in the above example? (if `someValue` is null)

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, I have tested and am aware that it didn't fail, the question was opened to identify whether there are any cases to be aware of, where I'd have to check for nulls before using string interpolation.

Comment: Run it and see?

Comment: @Jamesthorpe, thanks, I have run it. The point that it seems I didn't get across so much is if there are drawbacks to using it. I can see the question would benefit from having been rephrased...

Comment: I think your "different question" is off-topic, since it's too broad.

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious, but if you have $"Value is {someObject.someValue}" and someObject is null then it will throw a NRE, so you should use the null-conditional operator: {someObject?.someValue}. That's a case to be aware of.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

That's just the same as `string.Format("Value is {0}", someValue)` which will check for a `null` reference and replace it with an empty string.  It will however throw an exception if you actually pass `null` like this `string.Format("Value is {0}", null)`.  However in the case of `$"Value is {null}"` that `null` is set to an argument first and will not throw.

Comment: sorry it was only true for objects, when you pass a null string it doesn't throw

Comment: @SelmanGenç It doesn't throw for any nullable type.  The documentation seems to be wrong.

Comment: It throws if it sees you as having [passed `null` for the `args` parameter](http://imgur.com/6tiMwOZ) itself, rather than a null element

Comment: Ah I was actually doing `Console.WriteLine("{0}", null);` which does ignore the `null`. I was assuming it just passed everything to `string.Format`.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense

Comment: FWIW, the `Console.WriteLine` [ends up here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,c07c3772222caaff), where the null arg is wrapped up in a `ParamsArray`, while the direct call [ends up here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,691a34e179b91fdb,references) where it does the null ref check before hitting a different constructor of `ParamsArray`.

Answer (score 31):

From [TryRoslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayUAJ0iwQfdKgBqVIsFQwAvDAjAiRHLLnJF0GOgRxLS/TAAkAIk3bdYOkxVqPOgC+rmbsgdiBQA=), it's decompiled as;

```
string arg = null;
string.Format("Value is {0}", arg);
```

and `String.Format` will use empty string for `null` values. In [The Format method in brief](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Format_Brief) section;

> If the value of the argument is `null`, the format item is replaced with
>   `String.Empty`.

Comment: That seems to have changed. It's now decompiled as: string str = null;
        string text = "Value is " + str; The null string is still replaced with String.Empty.

Comment: @cfwall Yes, but that won't matter too much since for `+` operator, C# compiler internally translates it to `String.Concat` static method and it _still_ behaves like `string.Empty` when you handle `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the behavior depends on which underlying formatting methods are called, and the implementation of these can change over time. If you get a null formated into the string such as "(null)", it is not sure this will stay the same over several years. In some newer version of .NET it can start throwing an exception.

So I think the most safe approach is to make some condition to avoid using the null. Write a simple ternary operation like:

```
int? someValue = 5;
var valueStr = (someValue is not null) ? someValue.ToString() : string.Empty;
var myString = $"Value is {valueStr}";
```

It is an extra line of code, but at least the behavior is controlled.

Comment: I gave this a vote even though it may not be a direct answer to the question, it makes good sense.